# Doesnt outputs some cities

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

Well. Can someone explain to noob why is my code for example working with some cities like Odessa, London, Barcelona, Berlin. But does not work with Perm, Moscow, Athens and some a lot of another cities?

Changing names in quotes

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr:    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
 ?s rdfs:label "Moscow"@en .
 ?s dbo:populationTotal ?numberOfInhabitants .  
 ?s dbo:country ?country .
 ?s dbo:leaderTitle ?cityHead
}
```

Wanna have query that will work with whatever city would be in the quotes.

Comment: because not every city has all the information you're trying to get

Comment: `PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbr:    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
 ?s rdfs:label "Moscow"@en .
 OPTIONAL {?s dbo:populationTotal ?numberOfInhabitants .  }
 OPTIONAL {?s dbo:country ?country .}
 OPTIONAL {?s dbo:leaderTitle ?cityHead }
}`

Comment: as you can see when you execute my query, and as I also mentioned in your Wikidata question, multiple entities can have the same label, so you'll get multiple rows

Comment: any reason for using DBpedia now instead of Wikidata?

Comment: Now i see, thank you very much. About DBpedia and Wikidata - i'm trying both

Comment: Also, you may be happier with results from [DBpedia Live](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) than from [DBpedia (Snapshot)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) (which is still populated with the 2016-10 dataset).